# Pdf of signal that is sum of continuous and discrete variables

Tags: probability, signal-processing

What is the pdf of a signal y = x + n where x takes the values {-1,0,1} with equal probability and n is independent of x and has a pdf

$$ fn(n)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{L}(1-\frac{|n|}{L}) \,,~~~|n|\leq L\\ 0 \,,~~~|n|>L \end{cases}$$

What is the probability of error?

What happens for $$L \rightarrow \infty $$

Comment: $y$ does  not have a pdf.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the problem does mention that we need to find the pdf of receiving signal y (random variable).

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned}F_{Y}\left(y\right) & =\frac{1}{3}P\left(1+N\leq y\mid X=1\right)+\frac{1}{3}P\left(N\leq y\mid X=0\right)+\frac{1}{3}P\left(-1+N\leq y\mid X=-1\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{3}P\left(1+N\leq y\right)+\frac{1}{3}P\left(N\leq y\right)+\frac{1}{3}P\left(-1+N\leq y\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{3}F_{N}\left(y-1\right)+\frac{1}{3}F_{N}\left(y\right)+\frac{1}{3}F_{N}\left(y+1\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Taking the derivative we find:

$$f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\frac{1}{3}f_{N}\left(y-1\right)+\frac{1}{3}f_{N}\left(y\right)+\frac{1}{3}f_{N}\left(y+1\right)$$

Comment: Thank you!,  How do we find the probability of error though?

Comment: What is the definition of "probability of error" in this context? I am not quite familiar with the content of your question.

Comment: the question says to find the decision regions in the Maximum likelihood estimation and then calculate with precision the probability of error, which would be dependent of L, something like P(error) = g(L) , where g is a function.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you further on this. Feel free to remove acceptance.